# Can you configure AWS Security Groups to have sub groups or nested groups?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

**TLDR**

We have a long list of IP addresses in a single security group which is hard to manage. AWS makes it ***feel*** like you can have nested groups, but you can't. Am I right?

**Background**

I do not have any problems with configuring and using security groups. The question is more nuanced, this sets the background.

We have security groups configured to whitelist access to development instances/services. Due to our configuration pattern being a whitelist, we constantly have to add new IP addresses all the time, depending on where members of the team are working from. And crappy ISPs without static IP addresses.

This is not the problem. But picture a growing mess of IP addresses.

**Problem**

Occasionally we like to expunge this whitelist (because crappy ISPs) and make sure the IP addresses are relevant, up-to-date and should still be on the whitelist.

We are finding ourselves reluctant to do this as currently the only way to effectively "clean" the whitelist is to bin and start over.

AWS does not seem to present a neat way of either labelling records in security group rules, or to allow nested security groups.

**Current Work Arounds**

1. Have lots (potentially hundreds) of separate security groups, and make sure these are always attached to the relevant services.

   Pro: easy to label/identify IP addresses (eg Bob's Home IPs) so Bob can remove the old IP address and replace with his new one.

   Con: Each security group must be attached to the relevant instances and this list could get quite long.
2. Keep a separate IP/lookup list, and have one security group

   Pro: Means you only need one security group.

   Con: Having to keep two lists up-to-date, not very practical and you will get mis-matches.
3. Automation of some kind. Build a service which periodically checks the security group, and stores these IPs in DynamoDB along with some basic geo-ip/ISP information. Use as a reference.

   Pro: like #2 but automated. Not 100% accurate because geo-ip lookups never are.

   Con: Have to write and maintain the utility for something that feels like it should already exist.

**Hopeful Solutions**

1. Sub/nested security groups. The AWS configuration interface actually implies you can do this - but it does not work as expected. EG primary security group has rules which allow inbound traffic from other security groups - these in turn have the IP addresses logically grouped together.

   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

   > When you specify a security group as the source for a rule, this allows instances associated with the source security group to access instances in the security group. (Note that this does not add rules from the source security group to this security group.)

   I find that documentation a little contradictory. From experimentation it does not work.
2. Label each record. This plainly doesn't exist and would be a feature request for AWS.

**Am I missing something? How do other people manage large security groups?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct -- Security Groups cannot be nested.

If you are whitelisting instances **within your Amazon VPC**, you can use names to refer to other security groups. For example, you might have a `Web-SG` and an `App-SG`. The App-SG can permit access from the Web-SG. Any instance associated with Web-SG would then be able to communicate with any instance in the App-SG.

However, if you are whitelisting instances from **outside AWS**, then you will need to maintain the list of IP addresses within the security group(s) yourself.

The best approach would be automation:

- Maintain a 'master list' of whitelisted IP addresses in a database, spreadsheet, etc
- Automatically update the list whenever changes are made to the master list

This could be accomplished by a reasonably short program in your favourite programming language, calling commands like `authorize-security-group-ingress`.

**Bottom line:** Maintain your own fully-labelled list external to AWS, then make the security group match through automation.

Comment: Given the limits on the number of inbound entries, this seems destined for trouble. I'm not saying you're wrong, John. I'm wondering what's right. 

Even if I have 6 people on a team with 2 IPs each, each one with multiple port needs, that will exceed the limits of inbound entries pretty quickly. 

With a large team, I'd exceed the # of VPC SGs you can put on a RDS instance (5). While you can ask for more, this doesnt scale well. 

Seems obvious that I'm doing this wrong - but the docs aren't helping find the correct solution. Got a suggestion?

Comment: @riffrazor My assumption is that the limitation on Security Group rules is to avoid having to check too much information for every packet passing through the network. Complex rules would would add delays when sending and receiving data, so they probably had to set some limits to ensure traffic speed isn't overly impacted. I would recommend grouping your users into CIDR ranges, rather than requiring rules on individual IP addresses.

Comment: Yep, the reasoning makes sense. The solution is the challenge. In a traditional shop a better CIDR is a good solution. With remote people scattered all over creation, it's a non-starter. Scale is tolerable for us, so we can manage. I was just curious what a big shop would do that knew what they were doing:) Thanks.

Comment: Probably use VPN to add a security barrier, yet bring them into the same network.